# cassandra connection error: Unable to connect to any servers

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

cassandra doesn't work for my VM.

```
cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

when I use the command:

```
cassandra
......
INFO  07:55:31 Enqueuing flush of local: 578 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  07:55:31 Writing Memtable-local@2014850649(0.081KiB serialized bytes, 4 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  07:55:31 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmp-la-305-big-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1448697324414, position=105487)
INFO  07:55:31 Enqueuing flush of local: 51468 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  07:55:31 Writing Memtable-local@280469114(8.354KiB serialized bytes, 259 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  07:55:31 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/tmp-la-306-big-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1448697324414, position=117466)
INFO  07:55:32 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to normal
INFO  07:55:32 Compacted (64dd8610-95a5-11e5-af1d-a752adc4283f) 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/la-91-big,] to level=0.  20,658 bytes to 20,029 (~96% of original) in 2,376ms = 0.008039MB/s.  0 total partitions merged to 225.  Partition merge counts were {1:225, }
```

then cqlsh can work:

```
cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.1 | CQL spec 3.3.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

but a few minutes later, the cqlsh is down:

```
cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Anyone can help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The log files on the servers would probably tell you what you needed to know.

Comment: @Raedwald no errors found in log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the root cause: the memory is not enough. I create the linux swap, then everything is ok.

[how to add swap on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Can you please list the steps to create linux swap. I'm facing same the issue

Comment: Thank you very much @pangpang

Answer (score 3):

Sound like the server is going down after a few minutes. You should check the logs for the reason